# Which Type of Input is Least Vulnerable to Attack?

Tags: php, html, forum, bbcode, security

Which type of input is least vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) and SQL Injection attacks.

PHP, HTML, BBCode, etc. I need to know for a forum I'm helping a friend set up.

Comment: Vulverable to what exactly?  Hacking?  Cross site scripting?  SQL injection?

Comment: Cross site scrupting and SQL injection. Sorry, I thought I mentioned it in the question (got distracted and when I came back I hit submit without checking what I had written).

Comment: It'd be great if you could edit the actual question and put that stuff in there.  Can you also clarify what you mean by "input?"  My first reaction was you meant what type of form control was least vulnerable, in which case I would have to say the radio button!

Comment: I meant text boxes and forms, where users can put in information and have it sent to the server. Radio buttons and those types of items are obviously secure, so I don't have to worry about those.

Comment: Don't count on radio buttons being secure.  You should still sanitize the data on the server.  People could create an html page on their local machine, and make a text box with the same name as your radio button, and have that data get posted back. A more advanced user could use WebScarab, also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to know more about your situation.  Vulnerable how?  Some things you should always do:

- Escape strings before storing them in a database to guard against SQL injections
- HTML encode strings when printing them back to the user from an unknown source, to prevent malicious html/javascript

I would never execute php provided by a user.  BBCode/UBBCode are fine, because they are converted to semantically correct html, though you may want to look into XSS vulnerabilities related to malformed image tags.  If you allow HTML input, you can whitelist certain elements, but this will be a complicated approach that is prone to errors.  So, given all of the preceding, I would say that using a good off-the-shelf **BBCode** library would be your best bet.

Comment: Please don't escape strings to protect against SQL injections.  Use prepared statements with placeholders.

Answer (score 6):

*(I just posted this in a comment, but it seems a few people are under the impression that select lists, radio buttons, etc don't need to be sanitized.)*

Don't count on radio buttons being secure. You should still sanitize the data on the server. People could create an html page on their local machine, and make a text box with the same name as your radio button, and have that data get posted back.

A more advanced user could use a proxy like [WebScarab](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project), and just tweak the parameters as they are posted back to the server.

A good rule of thumb is to *always* use parameterized SQL statements, and *always* escape user-generated data before putting it into the HTML.

Comment: In Opera you can also edit the HTML or JS of a page therefore changing anything the user added to prevent you from doing something. Very cool for testing purposes, but makes it easy to mess with things.

Comment: Yeah, Firebug in Firefox allows for this too.

Answer (score 3):

None of them are.  All data that is expected at the server can be manipulated by those with the knowledge and motivation.  The browser and form that you expect people to be using is only one of several valid ways to submit data to your server/script.

Please familiarize yourself with the topic of XSS and related issues

- http://shiflett.org/articles/input-filtering
- http://shiflett.org/blog/2007/mar/allowing-html-and-preventing-xss

Answer (score 2):

Any kind of boolean.

You can even filter invalid input quite easily.

;-)

Comment: if(input != Bool.FileNotFound) //It's safe.  http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of BB code parsers that sanitize input for HTML and so on.  If there's not one available as a package, then you could look at one of the open source forum software packages for guidance.

BB code makes sense as it's the "standard" for forums.

Comment: I just want to note that it's important that BBCode itself is not a solution - it's the parser that would prevent XSS and SQL injection.  The fact that the rich text functionality is handled by BBCode markup is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The input that is the least vulnerable to attack is the "non-input".

Are you asking the right question?

Answer (score 0):

For Odin's sake, please don't sanitize inputs. Don't be afraid of users entering whatever they want into your forms.

User input is not inherently unsafe. The accepted answer leads to those kinds of web interfaces like my bank's, where Mr. O'Reilly cannot open an account, because he has an illegal character in his name. What is unsafe is always how you use the user input.

The correct way to avoid SQL injections is to use prepared statements. If your database abstraction layer doesn't let you use those, use the correct escaping functions rigorously (myslq_escape et al).
The correct way to prevent XSS attacks is never something like striptags(). Escape everything - in PHP, something like htmlentities() is what you're looking for, but it depends on whether you are outputing the string as part of HTML text, an HTML attribute, or inside of Javascript, etc. Use the right tool for the right context. And NEVER just print the user's input directly to the page.

Finally, have a look at the Top 10 vulnerabilities of web applications, and do the right thing to prevent them. http://www.applicure.com/blog/owasp-top-10-2010